# Proguard warning about ActionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android

I'm using Eclipse, And I'm using ActionBarSherlock.
Proguard was showing so many warnings for other libraries too, something about java/javax
and I fixed all of them by adding this line to Proguard:

```
-libraryjars C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar(java/**,javax/**)
```

Except this one, I don't know which library it needs and how to add it to -libraryjars:

```
Warning: com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView$LayoutParams: can't find referenced method 'LinearLayout$LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams)' in class android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

I don't want to use -dontwarn option, it will cause crashes in the future. I want to fix all of the warnings. only this one left to fix.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the end of your proguard config file. `-keep public class com.actionbarsherlock.**` and `-dontwarn com.actionbarsherlock.**`

Comment: I added this -keep public class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }                 and now it gives me more warnings about some methods. like this: Warning: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatJellyBeanMr2: can't find referenced method 'int getCapabilities()' in class android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo

Comment: plus the previous warning

Comment: thanks, but please read my question, I said I don't want to use -dontwarn